# CircuitMaker error "Duplicate item HRID" when trying to generate outputs

Tags: circuitmaker

What does this error mean, and how do I resolve it?

> Duplicate item HRID: SRC-<ProjectName>-130

Presumably it means that there's a duplicate of some item, but what am I looking for? I used CTRL-C/CTRL-V to duplicate some items, but they were not pasted on top of each other.

Problem happens when generating Gerber and/or NC Drill files.

There are no Google results for `circuitmaker "duplicate item hrid"`, and mostly spam results for `circuitmaker "duplicate item"`.

Update: I have gone through and clicked on every pad to make sure there weren't two on top of each other; the selection box that pops up when multiple items can be selected did not appear. I have also changed the designator for every pad to a different, unique value. Same error.

CircuitMaker 2.2.1 on Windows 10

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of error]

Update: Adding screenshot of folders/files to show there are no duplicates in the project

[image: Screenshot of folders/files]

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know what caused the problem, the workaround for me was to clone the project to a new one, and Generate Output from the clone. No changes were necessary on the clone; it "just worked." The original project, however, remains "broken," so this is more a workaround than a solution.

To Clone a project, right-click on the project name in the Projects sidebar (not a folder or file within the project), and click Clone.

[image: Right-click, Clone]

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [related](https://techdocs.altium.com/cn/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=295568):

> Remember that when pasting, two folders cannot have the same name in
> the same area of the folder structure. Trying to do so will result in
> a Duplicate Folder HRID error. And while the parent folder will not be
> pasted, its descendant structure will be, and at the top level of the
> vault folder structure. So if you are trying to quickly create a set
> of cloned folders under the same parent area of the vault 'tree', what
> you can do, is paste the folder structure to another temporary area of
> the main vault folder structure. Then simply rename the top level
> folder, make any other adjustments, then drag and drop back to where
> you really want the folder to be.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but I'm getting "Duplicate Item" not "Duplicate Folder". I have not manually created any folders at all; using whatever folders were added by the application when the project was created.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I saw the difference, but the good folks there shuffle things around so much I don't trust exact wording. Maybe it's a bad footprint (pads on top of each other or something like that) would be my other thought.

Comment: Fair enough; it's possible. I just clicked on every pad, and the pop-up that appears when multiple items can be selected did not appear for any of them. I'm guessing that means there are no pads directly on top of each other?

Would that also apply for traces/lines? It doesn't feel right to have to click on every single segment just to see if two are coincident...

Comment: I don't think traces would give that error. It's a naming error not a clearance or net antenna error.

Comment: I have also gone through and changed the designator for every pad and mounting hole to a unique value; same error.

Comment: So.... I created a clone (right-click > Clone...) of the project, changed absolutely nothing (even left the default name of <ProjectName - Copy>), immediately tried generating outputs again, and it works. The original one still gives the error, even after the clone generated successfully.

Comment: Ah, something was fixed in the cloning process, I guess. Shame they couldn't provide a more useful error message.

Comment: Yup, oh well, the workaround is easy enough and immediate problem resolved, so I guess that's it. Thanks for your help!